# Magento Bundle Product detail page have javascript errors

Tags: javascript, magento

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'specialTaxPrice' of undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reloadPrice' of undefined

I added **product_option.js** in the `Catalog_view` page as well but still these errors are firing.

Answer (score 0):

both methods specialTaxPrice and reloadPrice should come from

/skin/frontend/base/default/js/bundle.js

check what has happened with your product page and xml layouts. normally this file is appended. see bundle.xml

```
<label>Catalog Product View (Bundle)</label>
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bundle.js</name></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: bundle js already loading in the head section but still these errors are firing.

Comment: what kind of Theme is installed in this store? Themes may be or become incompatible if you upgrade magento. Just post contents of your current bundle.js for clarification.